# Forget middle intial in reference list – did I commit plagiarism?

Tags: citations, plagiarism

In my reference list, I forgot to add the middle name of the author and instead put “Bell, R.” instead of “Bell, R. J.”

Comment: This sounds pretty mild to me. Three or four years ago I came across a paper in arXiv (it was also under review at some journal at the time) in which a paper I co-authored with a couple of other people was listed as if I was the only author. I sent an email mentioning this, and all was fine. Or so I thought. A few months ago I happened to see the official published version of the paper, and although the bibliography entry was corrected, at the place where my co-authored paper is discussed, only my name is mentioned . . .

Answer (score 13):

Plagiarism is intentionally taking someone else's work or idea, and claiming it as your own. This is merely an error on your reference list - as long as the work you are referencing can still be found from the other information in the reference, this shouldn't be a problem.